# udisks mounting to /media/usb0 not /media/<volume_label> for usb3 drives

Tags: debian, mount, udev

I have a fully up-to-date, freshly re-installed debian sid box.  Before I re-installed running

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdc1
```

would mount the disk to `/media/<volume_label>`, however, it is currently mounting the drive to `/media/usb0`.

I assume I am missing a package or have something configured wrong, but for the life of me can not figure out what.

I have not (to my knowledge) modified the `udev` rules outside of debian's package management.  I have all the 'recommended' packages from udisks installed, but none of the suggested (as I don't need md, xfs, or reifer).

udisks version: 10.0.4.8 (downgrading to 10.0.4.7 didn't help).  I am sufficently confused, I don't know what other packages are relevant here.

Comment: I got your flag asking for migration to U&L... questions about Unix and Linux are fine on Super User, so you don't _need_ to migrate it. Since you already figured out the answer, it's not like you'll be more likely to get a solution - since you already have one. If you would still like to have it migrated regardless, let me know with another flag or a comment, and I'll get it over there for you.

Comment: @nhinkle Sent the flag before I figured out the answer.  I don't know either of these SEs particularly well, so I will leave the migration decision to you.

Comment: We'll leave it then @tcaswell - we generally avoid unnecessary migrations. In the future though you're welcome to ask linux questions on either site - it's up to you which community you think is most likely to have a good answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a usb-disk attached during installation and the installer added a line to `/etc/fstab` which mounted `/dev/sdc1` to `/media/usb0`.  Removing that line (and `/media/usb0`) fixed the problem.

(The *actual* problem is that I apparently can't read as I checked this at the very beginning and missed it)